# Show / Hide div if selected specific option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need if selected number 1 or 2 or 7 the div id show but if the other number div hide

```
<select class="custom-select" id="selectEmployer">
                                            <option selected>Vyberte</option>
                                            <option value="1">Employer 1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Employer 2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Employer 3</option>
                                            <option value="4">Employer 4</option>
                                            <option value="5">Employer 5</option>
                                            <option value="6">Employer 6</option>
                                            <option value="7">Employer 7</option>
                                        </select>
<div id="employer">SHOW</div>
```

Comment: Hide everything, then show the divs/ids that you want to be shown

Comment: Ok, can you show us your JS that you've tried to accomplish your desired goal? Then we can guide you to find a solution

Comment: I tried it like this https://codepen.io/Melwee/pen/ZEGeqLQ

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#selectEmployer").change(function() {
  $("#employer").hide();
  if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ["1", "2", "7"]) > -1) {
    $("#employer").show();
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#selectEmployer").change(function() {
  $("#employer").hide();
  if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ["1", "2", "7"]) > -1) {
    $("#employer").show();
  }
})
```

```css
#employer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" id="selectEmployer">
  <option selected>Vyberte</option>
  <option value="1">Employer 1</option>
  <option value="2">Employer 2</option>
  <option value="3">Employer 3</option>
  <option value="4">Employer 4</option>
  <option value="5">Employer 5</option>
  <option value="6">Employer 6</option>
  <option value="7">Employer 7</option>
</select>
<div id="employer">SHOW</div>
```

Comment: thank you you solution is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla javascript solution would be:

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById("selectEmployer");
var divElem = document.getElementById("employer");
var showFor = [1,2,7];
divElem.style = "display:none;"
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  var selectValue = parseInt(e.target.value);

  if (showFor.includes(selectValue)) {
    divElem.style = "";
  } else {
    divElem.style = "display:none;"
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="selectEmployer">
  <option selected>Vyberte</option>
  <option value="1">Employer 1</option>
  <option value="2">Employer 2</option>
  <option value="3">Employer 3</option>
  <option value="4">Employer 4</option>
  <option value="5">Employer 5</option>
  <option value="6">Employer 6</option>
  <option value="7">Employer 7</option>
</select>
<div id="employer">SHOW</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I hope this does what you need it to
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dm1w3a

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="selectEmployer"  (ngModelChange)="checkChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
                                            <option selected>Vyberte</option>
                                            <option value="1">Employer 1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Employer 2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Employer 3</option>
                                            <option value="4">Employer 4</option>
                                            <option value="5">Employer 5</option>
                                            <option value="6">Employer 6</option>
                                            <option value="7">Employer 7</option>
                                        </select>
<div id="employer" *ngIf="selectedValue === '1' || selectedValue === '2' || selectedValue === '7'">SHOW</div>
```

Comment: this is an Angular related solution, not quite universally applicable